# Unable to send laravel push notifications to ios mobile using godaddy server

Tags: ios, push-notification, laravel-5

I am doing project in laravel.  I have used davibennun/laravel-push-notification in my project to send push notifications to both android and ios devices.  At localhost its working fine but when i tried to send push notifications to ios devices from server then its showing me an error page.  I have attached the screenshot.  I am using godaddy as my server.  Any help would be appreciated and thanks in advance. [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using shared hosting on GoDaddy, then you won't have an access to `port 2195`. Port 2195 is closed for shared hosting. You can use other standard ports like 25, 80, 443.

You have to use `dedicated server` to achieve you goal.

Answer (score 0):

From this error it can be clearly seen the port 2195 is not enabled for communicating with APNS server on your webserver.

Make sure following outgoing ports are enabled and available for communication with APNS server.

- TCP port 5223 to communicate with APNs.
- TCP port 2195 to send notifications to APNs.
- TCP port 2196 for the APNs feedback service.
- TCP port 443 is required during device activation, and afterwards for fallback (on Wi-Fi only) if devices can't reach APNs on port 5223.

Reference Link: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203609